# Как по нажатию кнопки добавлять текст в форму?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

У меня задача: реализовать кнопку 'добавить код'(как на этом сайте), нажимаешь на кнопку и в форму добавляется тег `<code></code>`

Реализовать на HTML + Js не составило труда, вот

```
    <input type = "text" name = "text" id="text" value = "" />

<input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('text').value+='<code></code>'; return false;"
 value = "Добавить код" />
```

Но я не могу реализовать тоже самое на django

**forms.py**

```
    class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ['text']

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Questions
        fields =['q_name','slug', 'q_cat' ,'q_text']
```

**Шаблон(его часть)**

```
<!--    форма для добавления вопроса(поста) на страницу-->
<form action="" method="post">
{% for f in q_form %}

    <p><label class="form-label" >{{f.label}}: </label> {{ f }}</p>    

<div class="form-error">{{ f.errors }}</div>

{% endfor %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Задать вопрос"></p>

</form>
    {% else%}
    <h1>Зайдите на сайт</h1>
    {% endif %}
```

**Правка по вопросу:**

**forms.py**

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Questions
    fields =['q_name','slug', 'q_cat','q_text']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['q_text'].widget.attrs.update({'id': 'text_test'})
```

**Часть шаблона**

```
    {% for f in q_form %}
<p><label  id='text_test' class="form-label" for="{{ f.id_form_label }}" >{{f.label}}: </label>{{ f }}</p>
{% endfor %}
<input class="test_one" type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('text_test').innerHTML += html_to_insert.value+='<code></code>'; return false;"
 value = "Добавить код" />
```

Кнопка 'Добавить код', вместо того, чтобы добавить текст, ПУБЛИКУЕТ статью!!! Одним словом не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом - ничего не меняется, это также реализуется через `HTML + JS`.

Единственное различие, что теперь поле `text` находится внутри формы, которую генерирует `Django`, и все сводится к нахождению этого `HTML-элемента` через `JS`.

Приведу одно из возможных решений:

Вы можете в классе формы дополнительно переопределить метод `__init__` и в нём конкретному полю модели назначить нужный вам `HTML-id`, выглядит это так:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['text'].widget.attrs.update({'id': 'some_id'})
```

После чего, по аналогии с вашим примером, находить это поле по id, которое вы ему назначите, и работать с `HTML-кодом` этого элемента через атрибут `innerHtml`, примерно так:
`document.getElementById('some_id').innerHTML += html_to_insert;`

Comment: это не поможет ему, только потому... что он путает возможности фронта с бэком

Comment: @shol написал чуть подробнее)

Comment: да блин, ответ вот он, уже))) вся суть в том... что бэк, получив фронт или сгенерировав его может делать в него инжект, вот ему и нужен инжект с функционалом который он сам понимает)) я думаю ответ ему - все внешние воздействия такие как клики - это фронт, это js. всегда. пусть оставит джанго, фреймворк питона... питон не исполняется в браузере...))) P.S. коммент для него))

Comment: @Павел.спасибо за ответ, но всю документацию перерыл, но так и не понял, что значит 'добавлять нужный вам код в HTML-элемент через любой удобный метод (append, prepend, ...)'

Comment: @Костя добавил пример в ответ, можно и через innerHTML, вам так наверное проще будет, через prepend обычно готовые объекты добавляют

Comment: @Павел, я изменил вопрос с более точным описанием проблемы. Код все еще не рабоатет(((

Comment: @Костя html_to_insert - это не функция... вам нужно это заменить на тот код, который вы хотите добавить, вы хотя бы в браузере код и консоль откройте, посмотрите что происходит при ваших действиях

Comment: @Костя ну и публикует статью ваша кнопка, потому что у нее тип submit, любое нажатие отправляет собранную форму обратно в django.
В общем - информации в моём ответе достаточно, чтобы вы смогли разобраться самостоятельно, на каждом шаге вам тут помогать никто не будет.

Comment: @Павел, большое вам спасибо, я в js вообще не разбираюсь, поэтому такие глупые вопросы)

Comment: @Костя не за что, просто читайте документацию, разбирайтесь, очень полезно это делать по большей части самостоятельно, в будущем будет гораздо проще